# Solidity: Not able to call super function in trufffle test may be because of modifier defined

Tags: solidity, truffle, inheritance

When I am testing my class with truffle test ./test/testinheritance.js I am getting an error. "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert".

It seems to be error related to the condition that a function setHeir must be called by owner.
I am not sure how to set/get/check owner in test script so that I can test the contract.
Please help me to test this contract via script. 
The test script is

### The test script is

```
var DormantAssetFactory = artifacts.require("./DormantAssetFactory.sol");
var DormantAsset = artifacts.require("./DormantAsset.sol");
var dormantAssetAddress = null;

contract('DormantAssetFactory', function (accounts) {
  it("Let's call Heir function contract", async function () {
    var dormant_asset_factory = await DormantAssetFactory.deployed();
      (await dormant_asset_factory.newDormantAsset());
    //now get the Address of first contrac /This is not correct way but to show error
      dormantAssetAddress =
      (await dormant_asset_factory.getDormantAssetAt(0));

      var contractInstance = DormantAsset.at(dormantAssetAddress); //get contract at address
      //Call function of parent of current contract
//      console.log(contractInstance);
      var result =     
      (await contractInstance.setHeir(accounts[1]));
      //Just temp conditions
    assert.equal(1, 1, "Yes we called setHeir");
  });
```

### });

### Factory class is  DormantAsstFactory

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import './DormantAsset.sol';
contract DormantAssetFactory {
  // index of created DormantAsset contracts
  address[] public dormantAssets;
  uint256 public _heartbeatTimeout =1000000;
  function getContractCount()     public    constant    returns(uint contractCount)
  {
    return dormantAssets.length;
  }
  // deploy a new contract
  function newDormantAsset()    public     returns(address _newDormantAssetContract)
  {
    DormantAsset c = new DormantAsset(_heartbeatTimeout);
    dormantAssets.push(c);
    return c;
  }
```

### }

This contract created inside factory and it is inherited from this contract
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Heritable.sol

### Contract Class is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Heritable.sol';
contract DormantAsset  is Heritable {
  event Sent(address indexed payee, uint256 amount, uint256 balance);
  event Received(address indexed payer, uint256 amount, uint256 balance);
  function DormantAsset(uint256 _heartbeatTimeout) Heritable(_heartbeatTimeout) public {}
  function () public payable {
    Received(msg.sender, msg.value, this.balance);
  }
  function sendTo(address payee, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    require(payee != 0 && payee != address(this));
    require(amount > 0);
    payee.transfer(amount);
    Sent(payee, amount, this.balance);
  }
```

### }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of `contract DormantAsset` is `dormant_asset_factory` and you are trying to execute `setHeir()` function from `accounts[0]`. Function `setHeir()` has modifier `onlyOwner` and we already know that the owner is factory contract. You should implement function `callSetHeir()` in your **factory** contract and then call it from your test.

Hope it helps.

---

***Bonus:*** more readable way to write function with returned value

```
function newDormantAsset() public returns(DormantAsset c) {
     c = new DormantAsset(_heartbeatTimeout);
     dormantAssets.push(c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,
May you suggest some way so that I can make the account[0] as owner instead of dormant_asset_factory?
Special thanks for the Bonus :-).

Comment: Implement function `callTransferOwnership` and pass accounts[0] address as parameter. When you call this function from your factory contract it will reassign the owner.

Comment: [transferOwnership](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol) is located in Ownable.sol